# Ebean enhancement

Tags: java, maven, ebean

I'd like to create a small app, that uses Ebean as ORM. I've a little problem with the Ebean, and the enhancement, so I created a minimal example, that can be viewed here: https://github.com/vilmosnagy/ebean-example

It's a small Maven project, with one `Entity`, and one `Dao`. I wrote a test, where I'd like to save the entity into DB. (The DB is H2 in this example, 'cause to be small. I tried it with MySQL, but that didn't work either.)

When I run `mvn clean install`, I see the following lines in the output:

```
transform> pkg: com/example/entites
transform> cls: com/example/entites/BaseEntity  msg: interfaces:  entityInterface[false] transactional[false]
transform> cls: com/example/entites/BaseEntity  msg: performing entity transform
transform> cls: com/example/entites/BaseEntity  msg: ... adding intercept <init> in CONSTRUCTOR:()V OWNER/SUPER:java/lang/Object
transform> cls: com/example/entites/BaseEntity  msg: adding equals() hashCode() and _ebean_getIdentity() with Id field id index:0 primative:false
transform> cls: com/example/entites/BaseEntity  msg: enhanced
```

So, I think, my entity is enhanced succefully.

But when the tests run, I got the following exception:

```
Tests in error: 
  test_save(com.example.daos.BaseDaoTest): The type
[class com.example.entites.BaseEntity] is not a registered entity? If you don't
explicitly list the entity classes to use Ebean will search for them in the
classpath. If the entity is in a Jar check the ebean.search.jars property in
ebean.properties file or check ServerConfig.addJar().
```

I cannot find any solution. What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: I have not worked on spring. But in play I got same kind of error and I resolved it by specifying the entity class package like this in application.conf  - ebean.default="com.models.*"

Comment: There's no application.conf file, and nothing uses that. The Ebean enhancner knows, where are the files, so this isn't the problem. :(